# Leading zeroes in phone numbers

Tags: prononciation, nombres, oral, france, téléphone

For a phone number like this:

> 05 40 33 25 98

If you were to say it to someone, would you start:

> zéro-cinq quarante ...

Or because phone numbers in France usually start with zero, just:

> cinq quarante ...

For other cases:

> 01 42 05 50 50
>
> ... quarante-deux zéro-cinq cinquante ... ?
>
> 01 40 13 00 28
>
> ... treize zéro-zéro vingt-huit ?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should always pronounce leading zeros, and indeed say “*zéro zéro*” whenever a “block” of two digits is made of 0s.

> 01 47 20 00 01

is pronounced

> [zéro un, quarante-sept, vingt, zéro zéro, zéro un](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qBpA-BYxjZ8).

Comment: Arghhh, ça faisait bien deux ans que j'avais été épargné par cette pub. Ça mériterait un -1 ! Mais bon, +1 parce que tu as ajouté les virgules. Dans la pub on ne les entend pas et ça m'aura toujours empêché de retenir ce numéro (à vrai dire… tant mieux).

Comment: [Also relevant](http://youtu.be/NKyfx2uYupE?t=1m14s)